# A false conjecture by Goldbach

Tags: elementary-number-theory, conjectures

In 1752 Goldbach send this conjecture to Euler: "Every odd integer can be written in the form $p+2a^2$ where $p$ is a prime or $1$ and $a$ is a natural number (can be even 0)." This conjecture turned out to be false and my book asks me to prove that $5777$ cannot be written in such manner.

What I did is simply noted that if exists such $p$ it must be of the form $5777-2a^2$ and so $a$ mustn't be greater than $53$. Then I simply checked that for every values of $a$ from $0$ to $53$ $p$ is not prime.

Btw this is a very tedious way to prove this and may in a test I wouldn't be able to do this so I was wondering if there was any shorter way? (or my book just wanted me to make a lot of calculations for some reason.)

Comment: I ran a computer program and 5777 seems to be the smallest number with that property, 5993 is the next.

Comment: How did you check them all? It must have been *extremely* tedious. Did you use programming?

Comment: @PyRulez I am impressed that you check 53 values by hand, you must be very determined.

Comment: @user3105485 Yes I am :) I love math

Comment: @RenatoFaraone I suggest learning the basics of programming, the programme would have been as simple and short as (Python) :`is_prime = lambda x: all([x % i != 0 for i in range(2, int(x**0.5) + 1)]); print(any([is_prime(2*a**2) for a in range(0, 53 + 1)]))` Nonetheless I applaude your determination

Comment: Thx for the advice and the compliment :) @user3105485

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Observe that $5777\equiv 2\pmod 3$ and $2a^2\equiv 2\pmod 3$ unless $3\mid a$. Hence once you check that $5777-3$ is not twice a square, you need only check $a$ with $3\mid a$ (cutting down the effort by two thirds).

Likewise, $5777\equiv 2\pmod 5$, which allows you to drop all cases where $a\equiv \pm1\pmod 5$ (after checking that $5777-5$ is not twice a square).

Answer (score 11):

Say $p = 5777 - 2a^2$.

Now, if $a \equiv 1,2 \bmod 3$ then $p$ is divisible by $3$, which is impossible as we can check that $p \neq 3$.

If $a \equiv 0 \bmod 3$ then $p \equiv 17 \bmod 18$, so it is sufficient to only check a few values for $p$.

Answer (score 2):

At first we assume that $3\nmid a$. Then $a$ is one of the forms $3k\pm1$
Assume that \begin{align} 5777 &=p+2a^2\\
i.e  \quad 5777 &=p+2(3k\pm1)^2\\
i.e \quad   p&= 3(1925-6x^2\pm4x)\\
\end{align}
Since $p$ is a prime and $3|p$, so $p=3$.
Thus \begin{align} 5777 &=p+2a^2\\
\implies a^2&=2887
\end{align}
which is not a perfect square. This shows that $5777$ cannot be in the form $3k\pm1$.
We now assume that $3|a$ which causes $a$ to be in the form $3q$.
Now \begin{align} 5777 &=p+2a^2\\
\implies 5777&= p+18q^2\\
\implies p&\equiv 5777\quad  (mod \quad 18)\\
\implies p&\equiv 17\quad (mod\quad 18)\\
\end{align}
But $17$ and $18$ are relatively prime and hence $18\nmid p$.
The above congruence only holds for $p=17$ but for $p=17$
$5777  =17+2a^2\implies a^2=2880$ which is not an integer.
So this case also fails.
This follows the desired result.

Answer (score -1):

With a computer program, you can check increasingly, with cache of primes & powers.

Here is a `go` solution, that finishes in `2ms`:

```
package p46

import (
    "eric/algo/p_euler/p21"
)

// refer:   https://projecteuler.net/problem=46

const (
    steps = 1000
)

// search odd composite increasingly, with prime & square cache, till the missing one,
func SearchIncreasingly() int {
    var ps []int
    psMap := make(map[int]bool)
    dss := []int{2} // square * 2,
    nextSquareRoot := 2

    start := 2 // should avoid 1,
    end := start + steps
    for {
        // generate primes,
        newPs := p21.FindPrimesIncreasingly(start, end, ps)
        ps = append(ps, newPs...)
        for _, p := range newPs {
            psMap[p] = true
        }

        // generate dss,
    genSquare:
        for {
            ds := (nextSquareRoot * nextSquareRoot) << 1
            if ds < end {
                dss = append(dss, ds)
                nextSquareRoot++
            } else {
                break genSquare
            }
        }
        // fmt.Printf("start = %d, end = %d, ps size = %d, max p = %d, max dss = %d\n", start, end, len(psMap), newPs[len(newPs)-1], dss[len(dss)-1])

        // check odd composite,
    check:
        for x := start; x < end; x++ {
            if x%2 == 1 { // odd
                if _, ok := psMap[x]; !ok { // not prime
                    for _, ds := range dss {
                        if x <= ds { // all possible square checked,
                            break
                        }

                        other := x - ds
                        if _, ok2 := psMap[other]; ok2 { // found solution,
                            // fmt.Printf("\t%d = %d + %d\n", x, ds, other)
                            continue check
                        }
                    }
                    return x
                }
            }
        }

        start = end
        end += steps
    }
}
```

test case:

```
package p46

import (
    "fmt"
    "testing"
)

func TestSearchGapViaComposeIncreasingly(t *testing.T) {
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", SearchIncreasingly())
}
```

Result:

```
=== RUN   TestSearchGapViaComposeIncreasingly
5777
--- PASS: TestSearchGapViaComposeIncreasingly (0.00s)
```

Tips:

- `FindPrimesIncreasingly()` generate primes increasingly based on previous primes, you can try to impl it by yourself.

Comment: Notice that the URL says "math.stackexchange.com" and not "stackoverflow.com". While computer programs are useful sometimes, in this question OP requests for a real mathematical approach.